# C program to solve expressions with functions in it

Tags: c++, c, parsing

I tried to write a program some thing like a expression solver to support only the following functions

```
length();
substr();
concat();
```

Hence if the user inputs

```
concat('Int Part : ', substr(5.00+4.00, 0, 1))
```

the output should be

```
Int Part : 9
```

Is there any library to do this or is there any place I can learn how to do this kind of thing.

Comment: You can learn about this by searching for *parser* and *compiler* making tutorials. Not so much by asking here on SO though. You should also pick one language, creating a parser in C++ could be *wildly* different from creating one in C.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to write C-style C++, so he might mean that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Also, I suggest [bison and yacc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) which are powerful tools for what you need. But they are a bit complex.